# Am I missing libaries for discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
aiohttp                  3.7.4.post0
async-timeout            3.0.1
attrs                    21.4.0
certifi                  2021.10.8
cffi                     1.15.0
chardet                  4.0.0
charset-normalizer       2.0.10
discord                  1.7.3
discord-ext-alternatives 2021.4.13
discord.py               1.7.3
idna                     3.3
multidict                5.2.0
opuslib                  3.0.1
pip                      21.3.1
pycparser                2.21
PyNaCl                   1.4.0
requests                 2.27.1
setuptools               58.1.0
six                      1.16.0
typing_extensions        4.0.1
urllib3                  1.26.8
yarl                     1.7.2
youtube-dl               2021.12.17
```

This is a list of my libraries, am I missing any for discord.py?
My bot joins voice channels, but doesn't play audio.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `pip` in your prompt...

```
$ pip install discord.py
$ pip install discord.py[voice]
```

...it automatically provides all the libraries specified in the `requirements` file of the package.

---

EDIT: as @[TheFungusAmongUs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16177247/thefungusamongus) made me notice, in the documentation they said to install `discord.py[voice]`, that's not included in the `discord.py` requirements.

Comment: discord.py* not discord

Comment: I've both discord.py and discord package installed, I didn't know which of them was the right one. Anyway nice to see you on discord.py tag, it was some time without running into you in the comment sections

Comment: “discord” is a clone of discord.py. Nice to see you too:)

Comment: Shouldn't they also install discord.py[voice] as per [the installation tutorial](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#installing)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after about 2 weeks of trying to figure out the problem. I've been using Visual Studio Code, the code doesn't work there. I tested Visual Studio 2022 and the code works fine there without problems

Comment: Please edit the original question to let everyone know